# Google plus one counts lost after adding 'www' to website URL

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

After I changed my website URL in my Google+ page (from `http://unimojo.ir` to `http://www.unimojo.ir` for getting better SEO results) theses things are happening:

1. My home page *plus one count* got reset.
2. Before the change, by clicking on the *+1* button on any post in the page, it was adding the click to my home page *plus one* badge. But after the change it doesn't any more.

Anyone knows what I can do about it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
I formatted your question and fixed some grammar mistakes. A well formatted question receives more responses, because it takes less time to understand it. 
To create an ordered list you need to use `1.` (not `1-`) - see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.